# "difficult to pull off — he didn’t quite nail it"

Tags: meaning-in-context

*I thought everyone in the cast was very good — and several actors had really challenging characters like the seven-minute woman. **Al’s character was difficult to pull off — he didn’t quite nail it**.*

Source: https://jmmnewaov2.wordpress.com/2013/04/18/top-of-the-lake-closes-its-run-did-it-work-for-you/

Can you tell me what the bold passage exactly means. Especially "he didn’t quite nail it" I am not able to decipher. Does it mean that the Al's character is unconvincingly written?

Comment: [Nail](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nail) To discover or establish conclusively, to win, to fix. In the cited context, to *capture the essence of the character, to act the part very well*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: He says "Al's character" which could be interpreted as either "the character of Al" or "the character played by Al". I had to look up the article to realize Al is the character. David Wendham is the actor playing Al.

So, to rephrase what he said:

> The character of Al is difficult for an actor to portray correctly. The actor
>   [David Wendham] did not get it exactly right.

Later in the article, it says:

> Yes, I stand by my spotting Al as the perp even before Tui
>   disappeared. He just oozed creepiness — which is why I said the actor
>   didn’t nail his purpose.

So in this person's opinion, David Wendham acted in a way that made the character too creepy, giving away the fact that he was the villain too easily. He thinks that if David Windham had played Al less creepily, maybe it would have been more of a surprise who the villain turned out to be.

Answer (score 0):

*pull off* in this case means *manage to do something difficult or tricky.*
So, to *pull off* a character means to portray it no matter the costs.

As for *nail it*, it's just like saying *he made it nicely*. (You can get what the negative form means in your case.)

Comment: "Nail it" is to do it perfectly, to get it right.  To "hit the nail on the head". Similar to British "spot on".

Comment: @TRomano I was about to say *spot on* but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reactions. But I am still a little bit confused what the pronoun "he" represents. Probably Al's character. But given your explanation it would be more logic if he represented the actor in the sense that his perfrormace was not good.

Comment: "He" in this case is Al.  It's not the clearest sentence in the world, but it basically means "Al's character was difficult to portray, and he (Al) did not quite manage to do it convincingly."